# How can I attach a third computer to a shared internet connection?

Tags: home-networking, internet-sharing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Attach third computer to shared internet connection](https://superuser.com/questions/458454/attach-third-computer-to-shared-internet-connection)

have 3 computers, all of which I want on the internet. The first is a laptop, which has a wireless connection and an ethernet connection.
The second is a desktop, with 2 ethernet connections.
The third is a desktop, with 1 ethernet connection.
The laptop gets the internet from the wireless, and shares that on the ethernet connection to the first computer - this works fine. I want to attach the second desktop, so that it can have internet access.

I have tried to implement internet sharing on the first desktop, but it said it could not, because there was already an address with the shared network address (the laptop). I tried to create a bridge, but I was unable to get the internet on the second desktop - I may be missing something there.

Is it possible / what settings do I need for the second desktop to be able to access the internet by connecting it to the first desktop?

Comment: You tried to bridge the 2 ethernet interfaces on the first desktop?  Personally I'd spring for a cheap 4 port switch.   You are going to get annoyed at this setup because you have so many points of failure, problems troubleshooting because there are so many places you will have to identify the source of the problem, and you will find yourself troubleshooting alot anytime you need to open a port because it has to go through so many interfaces.  You also have three computers going through one wireless interface, which limits the speed you could transfer over a switch on a wired connection.

Comment: *"The laptop gets the internet from the wireless"* - What is this "wireless"? Is it on your premises and under your control? Is it just a wireless router + somekind of modem?  Do you really want to always have the laptop up & running in order for the other two PCs to have Internet access, and the first PC up for the second PC?  Is electricity that much cheaper than wire?

Comment: Here's a cheap 5-port switch: http://www.amazon.com/TRENDnet-TE100-S5-Ethernet-100Mbps-Auto-MDIX/dp/B000M2TAN4/ref=sr_1_1?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1344295502&sr=1-1&keywords=4-port+ethernet

Comment: further to what @AaronLS mentioned, you can get a switch with a wireless component that will connect to your original wireless- meaning you don't even have to run a cable between them. For example your wireless could be downstairs, and this wireless switch could be upstairs, connected to the desktops. This also has the advantage of extending your wireless range

Comment: I my opinion, a switch is the way to go. Much easier that fooling around with Internet Connection Sharing and probably faster.