# Attach third computer to shared internet connection

Tags: networking, windows-7

I have 3 computers, all of which I want on the internet.
The first is a laptop, which has a wireless connection and an ethernet connection.
The second is a desktop, with 2 ethernet connections.
The third is a desktop, with 1 ethernet connection.
The laptop gets the internet from the wireless, and shares that on the ethernet connection to the first computer - this works fine. I want to attach the second desktop, so that it can have internet access.

I have tried to implement internet sharing on the first desktop, but it said it could not. I tried to create a bridge, but I was unable to get the internet on the second desktop.

How can I connect the second desktop to the first desktop, and have it accessing the internet?

Comment: How're you connected to the phone system - do you have a 3G dongle on your laptop / a router plugged into the phone socket / something else?

Comment: I have 3 computers running on a shared connection at home with no problems. You could be having COnflicting IP issues. Put "conflicting IP shared connection" in Google search... a bunch of articles on how to solve this will come up.

Comment: The laptop picks up a wireless signal from a router.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart, I haven't used SuperUser, so didn't know. Is it possible to move?

Comment: A moderator can, I cannot. It may be just as easy to copy/paste and delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place an ethernet switch on the ethernet link of the laptop

attach both desktops to that switch

---

since you got no extra hardware ...

internet connection sharing (ICS) remains as it is on the laptop.

find out what ip subnet you are using. -> choose another 2 private nets e.g. 192.168.10.0/24 and 192.168.11.0/24 ... i'll refer to them as XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX and YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY

now configure the ethernet port on the laptop:
IP: XXX.XXX.XXX.1
subnet mask 255.255.255.0

ethernet port 1 on desktop 1 (connect to laptop ethernet)
IP: XXX.XXX.XXX.2
subnet mask 255.255.255.0
default gateway XXX.XXX.XXX.1
primary DNS: 8.8.8.8

ethernet port 2 on desktop 1 (connect to desktop 2 ethernet port 1)
IP: YYY.YYY.YYY.1
subnet mask 255.255.255.0

ethernet port 1 on desktop 2 (connect to desktop 1 ethernet port 2)
IP: YYY.YYY.YYY.2
subnet mask 255.255.255.0
default gateway YYY.YYY.YYY.1
primary DNS 8.8.8.8

now you need to enable the IPRouting on desktop 1 ... for windows XP or 7 that would be a new registry key:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters
IPEnableRouter
type dword
value 1

for a linux system ...  echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

(a windows machine needs a reboot after you enable the IP Router)

Comment: Sure, this would work, but relies on having a spare switch. I have a spare ethernet cable.

Comment: See my conflicting IP comment. You're assigned one IP address by your Internet provider therefore having multiple computers without having a router split it will block you from the Internet. Without having an extra router you need to manually program IPs into your PCs under TCP/IP settings.

Comment: @3Pi see edit ...